# Swift Error convertPoint(CGPoint, to: UITableView)

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, nsindexpath, cgpoint

So I have a custom `tableview` and in that tableview I have a button, an image, and 2 labels. Each of these items gets filled with json data from a mysql server using php. I converted my project from Objective-C to Swift and in doing so I got this error. This is one of the most important codes in my project because since the user clicks the follow button it moves the array to other arrays, and in doing that it gives a special row number to the cell so all the images, labels, and the button knows which is which to display.

I tried switching it so `.convert()` but just errors so I left it how it was orginally.

**The code for the button**

```
// Follow Button
@IBAction func followButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {

// Adding row to tag
var buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convertPoint(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
var indexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!

// Creating an action per tag
if indexPath != nil {

    // Showing Status Labels
    var cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(atIndexPath: indexPath)!
    cell.firstStatusLabel.isHidden = false
    cell.secondStatusLabel.isHidden = false

    // Change Follow to Following
    (sender as AnyObject).setImage(UIImage(named: "follow.png")!, for: .normal)
    cell.followButton.isHidden = true
    cell.followedButton.isHidden = false
    self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

    // ----- Inserting Cell to Section 0 -----
    followedArray.insert(testArray[indexPath.row], at: 0)
    myTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)

    // ----- Removing Cell from Section 1 -----
    testArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    var rowToRemove = indexPath.row
    self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: true)

    self.myTableView.endUpdates()

 }
}
```

**The Error**

[image: error picture]

**Errors with new code**

Pictures so its easier to read

[image: error]

[image: error 3]

[image: error 4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertPoint` is changed in Swift 3 like `convert(_:to:)`.

```
var buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
```

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622442-convert) for more details.

**Edit:**

For your first warning instead of usinf `indexPath != nil` you need to use `if let` and for that label error you need to cast your cell to customCell that you are using.

```
var buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
if let indexPath = self.tblSubscriber.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {
     //Cast your `UITableViewCell` to CustomCell that you have used
     var cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(atIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell 
}
```

For your `deleteRows` error you need to specify the `UITableViewRowAnimation` not `true` or `false`.

```
self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: rowToRemove, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
```

For more detail about [`UITableViewRowAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation) check documentation.

Comment: I get 3 errors in doing this to the rest of the code

Comment: I added them at the bottom

Comment: @BroSimple Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying this code in swift3 then the above method is updated to
[func convert(_ point: CGPoint, 
        from view: UIView?) -> CGPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622424-convert) you can use it like this

```
var buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.myTableView)
```

I have checked it in Playground and it is working.